# How to make a task complete before running another task

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am using the Microsoft Web API 2.2 Client to request data from an API endpoint. After I get the data I run x number of DoSomeWork.  I want to make sure the data loads first before I run the DoSomeWork functions.

Based on the code below I was expecting the following output.

> "Starting GetSomething" 
>   "Done with GetSomething" 
>   "Start work# 1"
>   "Start work# 2"

But I getthe following
"Starting GetSomething"
"Start work# 1"
"Done with GetSomething"
"Start work# 2"

```
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Task getSomethingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>GetSomething());
            getSomethingTask.Wait();
            Task[] tasks = new Task[2] {
                 Task.Facotry.StartNew(()=>DoSomeWork(1)),
                 Task.Facotry.StartNew(()=>DoSomeWork(2))
            };
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           throw ex;
        }
    }
    static async Task GetSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting GetSomething");
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SOME_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/v1/somethings");
            somethingList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeObject>();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done with GetSomething");
    }
    static async Task DoSomeWork(int workNumber)
    {
       Console.Writeline("Start work#" + workNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing asynchronous programming (i.e., I/O-bound), you want to avoid `StartNew`, `Wait`, and `WaitAll`. Instead, use `async` and `await` for almost all logic.

Since this is a Console app, you do need a single `Wait` so that the main thread doesn't exit. This should be the only `Wait` in your entire app:

```
static void Main()
{
  MainAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
  await GetSomethingAsync();
  await Task.WhenAll(DoSomeWorkAsync(1), DoSomeWorkAsync(2));
}

static async Task GetSomethingAsync()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Starting GetSomething");
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  ...
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/v1/somethings");
  somethingList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeObject>();
  Console.WriteLine("Done with GetSomething");
}

static async Task DoSomeWorkAsync(int workNumber)
{
  Console.Writeline("Start work#" + workNumber);
}
```

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `getSomethingTask` is finishing immediately because you aren't `await`ing `GetSomething()`.

Try this:

```
Task getSomethingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await GetSomething());
```

or simply:

```
GetSomething().Wait();
```

Though I don't think you're really gaining anything by creating a new thread and immediately waiting for the result on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `await` from a thread, you yield control back to its parent thread.

In this case, this is your offending line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/v1/somethings");
```

As soon as you do that, your `GetSomething` thread yields control back to the `Main()` thread, which is why you see your `DoSomeWork` tasks executing.

If you get rid of those `await` calls in `GetSomething` and replace them with synchronous calls instead, you'll get the behavior that you want.

For more info, see Microsoft's async programming guide here (especially step #6 where it talks about `await`): http://msdn.microsoft.com/async